# Code gives error for accdb files

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datetime, oledb, dao

The below code adds a column of datatype "Date/Time" with format "Long Time" to an access table of .mdb  file. But if i replace the mdb file with accdb then adding column won't work. So i want alternative code which can add column of datatype "Date/Time" with format "Long Time".

The code which i use

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As Field

Dim JetEngine As New dao.DBEngine
Dim p 
db = JetEngine.OpenDatabase("D:\Employee.accdb")

tdf = db.TableDefs("detail")
fld = tdf.CreateField()
With fld
     .Name = "MyDateTime"
     .Type = 8
      .Size = 8
End With

tdf.Fields.Append(fld)
p = fld.CreateProperty("Format", 10, "Long Time")
fld.Properties.Append(p)
```

I get error like "Unrecognized database format 'D:\Employee.accdb'."  for the code

```
db = JetEngine.OpenDatabase("D:\Employee.accdb")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Do you get an error? If so, then what does the error message say and which line of code triggers it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the References for your project. If you are using the reference

> Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

(which appears in the References list as "DAO") then your code will work for `.mdb` files but not for `.accdb` files. You can support both file types without major modifications to your code if you simply remove that reference and replace it with

> Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library

(which appears in the References list as "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao").

Comment: I was searching for this from long time. Your suggestion helped me a lot.Thank you..